# Python Pandas to_datetime error on format

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

The date in the CSV cell is like this: `08-09-22 14:07:00 AM`

When I use

`df["time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["time"],format="%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S %p")`
or
`df["time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["time"],format="%d-%m-%Y %H:%M")`

it shoots this

> ValueError: time data '08-09-22 14:07' does not match format '%d-%m-%Y
> %I:%M:%S %p' (match)

or this error

> ValueError: time data '08-09-22 14:07' does not match format '%d-%m-%Y
> %I:%M' (match)

If I use the automatic format detection, it fails by not covering all timelines. The Hour is in the `00-12` format.

PS: the time data displayed in the error misses seconds and PM/AM.

Comment: Try automagic detection with `dayfirst=True`: `pd.to_datetime(df["time"], dayfirst=True)`. If this fails, can you provide an exhaustive list of the possible cases?

Comment: Thank you @mozway it solved my problem. Still i would be curious ( maybe for others in the future ) why the " manual " format did not work in that context

Answer (score 0):

The year is given with two digits only so it should be a "y" not a "Y" in the format.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.to_datetime('08-09-22 14:07:00',format="%d-%m-%y %H:%M:%S")
```

Gives :

```
Timestamp('2022-09-08 14:07:00')
```

"Y" stands for four digits year description :

```
pd.to_datetime('08-09-2022 14:07:00',format="%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

Gives :

```
Timestamp('2022-09-08 14:07:00')
```